# laravel - change value in array for API Resources

Tags: laravel

```
{
"data": {
   "username": "candy",
   "certificates": [
   {
   "id": 11,
   "category_id": 1,
   "certname": "cert name test",
   "created_at": "2018-08-18 00:58:12",
   "updated_at": "2018-08-18 00:58:12"
   }
   ]
 }
}
```

Above is a response by using Eloquent: API Resources.

I would like to put category name instead of category_id.

Below is resource class

```
    public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'nickname' => $this->nickname,
        'certificates' => $this->certificates,
    ];
}
```

certificates are in array (hasMany relationship)

certificates belongsTo category

Comment: Not really sure what you’re asking here... what are you trying to do?

Comment: change like "category_id": 1 to "category": engineering

Comment: i want to show string instead of integer.

Comment: i can change by using Accessor but want to know other ways.

Comment: Use https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources or when you’re in the controller, use a `map()` on the collection to rebuild the array https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map

Comment: thanks okay will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, in the resource class you can fetch category name for each certificate and attach it.

```
public function toArray($request)
{

    $certificateList = $this->certificates;

    foreach($certificateList as $ceritificate) {

         // fetch only the category name from the database.
         // attach to the certificate.

         $categoryName = Category::where('id', $certificate->category_id)->pluck('name')->first();
         $certificate->setAttribute('category_name, $categoryName);
    }

    // then as usual
    return [
         'nick_name' => $this->nick_name,
         'certificates' => $certificateList
    ];
}
```

Comment: thanks. I slightly modified your code and solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This Might Help, 
Run a foreach loop

```
$category = "Your SELECT Query";
foreach ($category as $value) {
               $categoryId = json_decode($value->category_id);
               $x = Category::select('certname')->whereIn('id', $categoryId)->get();
               foreach ($x as $as) {
                   $y[] = $as->certname;
               }
               $value->certname = $y;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do it like this

in controler

```
 return    CertificateResource::collection(Certificate::with('category')->get());
```

in CertificateResource

```
 return [
    'nickname' => $this->nickname,
    'certificates' => $this->certificates,
    'category_name'=>$this->whenLoaded('category', function () {
            return $this->category->category_name;
        }),
];
```